# Make Gimbap cutter

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

[Gimbap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbap)(김밥) is Korean food, somewhat looks like sushi roll.

Here is Korean emoticon represent Gimbap : `@))))))))))`

Your quest is make ASCII Gimbap cutter.

## Rule

Input is string made with only `@` and `)`.

Output *cuts* every valid Gimbap with `)`, and then add   `@` between them. So for example `@))` to `@) @)`.

*Valid Gimbap* starts with `@` and followed by any amount of `)`.

If there is no valid Gimbap, output is blank.

## Input and output

```
Input | Output
@))))) | @) @) @) @) @)
@))))))) | @) @) @) @) @) @) @)
@))@))) | @) @) @) @) @)
@) | @)
)) | 
@ | 
@@)@@@))) | @) @) @) @)
@)@)@)) | @) @) @) @)
@@@)) | @) @)
))@) | @)
```

## Winning condition

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

from [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17750/87110)

Comment: Is the rule equivalent to "output one copy of `@) ` for every `)` in the input not counting those before any `@`? May our output include a trailing space, like `"@) @)  "`?

Comment: It is. And output can include a trailing space.

Comment: Do we have to output a space delimited string or can we output an array of slices? Also, are we limited to those 2 characters or can we use any 2 characters of our choosing?

Comment: My first time trying to read the title, "Gimp-bat clutter? What?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 32 bytes

```hs
f(')':s)=f s
f s=do ')'<-s;"@) "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBboMwEETv/oqRVSlYMafc2iD50q9AHKwUUlQwVtZcqn573XXBCq2SYCx5583Oyn639NEOQ4xdsVO7Z1JVBxK8q7cJrBxLepFGQcbQUiBUqAuu0yc1Etn8Umlkeov/c5mHIQtZqsW3ks3RKGNupOSItO4wsyV5yHVoI0TROz8H0gj2cm4DKb777D57j9@XENMcEmd1tB4dFrsYbe9Y85feBTyhqFOO5gzNDerrT4VjCQ48rL15EtZoDTeF16Edk4A6dSXLfi8hm0Znm4rfp26wZ4rlyfsf)

Recursion beats using `span` for removing the initial `(`'s.

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes**

```hs
f s=do ')'<-snd$span(<'@')s;"@) "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBjoIwFEX3fMVNYwKNZTVLMenGryAsGgUlQml4ZWP89um0A41o1LaLvnfuuzftRdG17jrnGtD@NCDlaZGTPm3IKJ0VqUw57ZjkYM7WZAl7lJmvw2ICgawO4wKRvuMvKvnVZCZzNesWsrpKLuUbl2gR9gcm1ySGPEKrJMlabSZLAlaN59oS92@f9K01@P@JZJhs4L7bK4MGszzpVat9z4ytttggK4OP8B7CD/D7U4Uihzf8WWZjEhZrAT3YQ1f3oYEyTAXJdsvAqkpEGXe/x6ZTZ3L50Zg/)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript, <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
s=>s.split(/(?<=@.*)\)/).fill``.join`@) `
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoAgEEDRq0QrJ2i8QJYHaaGYhjE40kjXt1r8x7/84yXcuba58BF7Ml3MKiiVclNabYuxOMEOGjBlIufw4lychcH1wEWYIhKfKqkRAOzfx/f9BQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
@ｓｊ∑Ｌ@) ×
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=QCV1RkY1MyV1RkY0QSV1MjIxMSV1RkYyQ0AlMjklMjAlRDc_,i=JTI5JTI5JTI5JTI5JTI5QCUyOSUyOUAlMjklMjklMjk_,v=8)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 53 bytes

```c
i;f(char*_){for(i=1;*_;!i&*_++&&printf("@) "))i&=*_;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoMwEETv@Yo0h5A1lrbnbSD/ISISmnYPVdH0UvHb08RauwvDg5mBcce7czESeuUe7Vg0MPt@VGQuWDR4IFk0Wks5jNQFr4QFLgBImmQu8dlSp2Bma5MHV9VmZimTT5Q/2tnumHXjVSxY@3fzf9FukLuCLcjSNq7SFE7mjHSd6H3rvQoOThuuUwBJ63J4hUmJ1GU5UVENyJb4AQ)

```c
i;f(char*_){for(    *_;                      )      }   //loop over the string:
                i=1;   !i&                    i&=*_;    //skip leading `)`s
                       !i&*_++&&printf("@) ")           //and print "@) "for each `)` thereafter
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <sup><s>48</s></sup> 47 bytes

```javascript
x=>"@) ".repeat(x.split(/(?<=@.*)\)/).length-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDNCsIwDL73KcpOrbBOzzoNgk@hQuus26SupatjB9@9dh3iYJqEQL4fQnIXnWgLWxuXNvoqfScsLuvHRZj90ylpcY59n28ToDhhVhopHOlZa1TtSEZ2mxzYgp5oRpmSTemqdEX9mgMdAr9wsE0KjfgP5svDH2PEUOQQxAYUYK4O0iFnKEwwNKyJAx9P4Yizm7YHUVSkx/kWF7pptZJM6ZJM3/G5nQc3Py7PYb1/Aw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <sup><s>53</s></sup> 49 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...x].map(y=>y<"0"?m+=s&&"@) ":s=1,s=m="")&&m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDdCoIwFL7fU4xdDEc17LaajaCnEGHLrAznxmai0LsvXUGCdc7hwPl@@ODcZStdbkvTrGp9LnwrLbyW6iTN4dFUhYUM@o4lKaW0y6iSJupZ0u9QjPZqwRzGiBOINo6tl44phhDBWPmt4GQs@IQDPRnwxn8wX57/MQYMBA7wsDjhfK4epGPPUD7BwBgTDkGdqcpGAEEv2h5lfos6yBKY69rpqqCVvkbTh0TdxzC4RRpnQ7x/AQ)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 60 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/(@?)(\)*)/g,(_,a,b)=>a&&b.replace(/./g,"@) "))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBRC4IwFIXf9ytGD7IbNnsP7RL0KyratGXGcjJN9tB/t2mBgnU3BvvOORy4d9nKOrNF1axKc1FdKy3Ni0cqq92z0crSmHYuThy3qtIyUyxiuAV2hCVEecjOoQxTiBMZBOlo4V5aINAFQLcRCP3QF/VkcsmH/1BGHf8EB0YGjeDwICDO3d7anxnFCSN9zfARvK500Qgi@NXYvcxuzNE4oZkpa6MV1yZn090w9w34tDisT76@ewM)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 14 bytes

```
^\)+|@

\)
@)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPy5GU7vGgYsrRpPLQVPh/38HTRDgglAQhgOE5gKRXA4Omg4OUBEQBNIgLhdIGQA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^\)+|@
```

Delete leading `)`s and all `@`s.

```
\)
@)
```

Replace all `)`s with `@)`s. (Note: trailing space.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda s:'@) '*s.lstrip(')').count(')')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7RCsIgGIXvfYqf3ag1BnU5GPgWXVTEqq0JpqKOEfTu9mtBg5WKHL9zPGofYTB6G/vmEFV7P19b8DUVHOjKV8oHJy2jnPLqYkYdsozTIFUHm5qALyFAA66dTlLbMTBeeask5uAJlBNwnUe/Zx61dVKHRAjIHrTJGqSGfcCaNQV6xMpPrNg5o291UQLDVBl4FDwN7MXPzRZ58x/O1xd/LmZGskdE3gQXYpnGaJoLKmaMpGfy4QU)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ṣṀḊẎ”@pK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsUPdzY83NH1cFffo4a5DgXe////1wQBAA)

-1 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 26 bytes

```perl
$_=s/^.*?@//&&'@) 'x y/)//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3RCsIwDEXf@xUBZbOC1hefRMx/iMqQ6ipbW9oMFfx2a1sFB9MkBHLuTWKla5ZhfFhPvG0UCRB8u9itYASXzhOcjAPXaa30GaiWQDLCY@Wlh6ui2nQETkZTWxF9PG265sV@Pt2gEEVRIofyBnfBhQgBeQp4QKS9Ym/@Q/nq@GcxM5Y1hrkhRxy6ozXlgGKPsfQmD09jSRntw8w2Lw)

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY3RCsIwDEXf@xUBZbOC1hefhpj/EJEh1VW2trQZKvjt1rYKDqZJCOTcm8RK167D9LCZedsqEiD4brWvYAKX3hOcjAPXa630GaiRQDLCY@2lh6uixvQETkZTVxN9PF265sVyvkUhiqJEDuUN7hWvQkCeAh4Q4aDYm/9Qvjr@WcyMZY1hbsgRx@5oTTmiOGAsvcnD01hSRvuwsO0L "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
')Û'@KS'@ìðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXfPwbHUH72B1h8NrDm84vPf/fwcHTQcg1tT8r6ubl6@bk1hVCQA)

**Explanation**

```
')Û            # trim leading ")"
   '@K         # remove all "@"
      S        # split to list of characters
       '@ì     # prepend "@" to each
          ðý   # join on spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 58 bytes

```
@set s=%1@
@set s=%s:*@=(%
@set s=%s:@=%
@echo%s:)=@) %
```

Takes input as a command-line parameter. Explanation:

```
@set s=%1@
```

Suffix an `@` in case the input doesn't contain any.

```
@set s=%s:*@=(%
```

Delete up to the first `@`, replacing it with a `(` to ensure that the string is not empty (because `%:%` doesn't work on empty strings). The `(` also makes the `echo` work if the rest of the string is empty.

```
@set s=%s:@=%
```

Delete any remaining `@`s.

```
@echo%s:)=@) %
```

Expand any remaining `)`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 15 bytes

```
r/^\)+|@/ ¬mi'@
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVM&code=ci9eXCkrfEAvIKxtaSdA&input=IkBAKUBAQCkpKSI)

```
r/^\)+|@/ ¬mi'@     :Implicit input of string
r                   :Remove
 /^\)+|@/           :  "@"s and leading ")"s
          ¬         :Split
           m        :Map
            i'@     :  Prepend "@"
                    :Implicit output, joined with spaces
```

### Alternative

```
e/^\)/ è\) Æ"@)
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVM&code=ZS9eXCkvIOhcKSDGIkAp&input=IikpKUBAKUBAQCkpKSI)

```
e/^\)/ è\) Æ"@)     :Implicit input of string
e                   :Recursively remove
 /^\)/              :  Leading ")"
       è\)          :Count remaining ")"s
           Æ        :Map the range [0,Count)
            "@)     :  Literal string
                    :Implicit output, joined with spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 10 bytes

```
Z¡¦JS'@ìðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/6tDCQ8u8gtUdDq85vOHw3v//NTUdHIDIQVNTEwA)

[This bug](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50573719#50573719) forces me to use the legacy version. This is the code for the current version of 05AB1E (11 bytes):

```
'@¡¦JS'@ìðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f3eHQwkPLvILVHQ6vObzh8N7//zU1HRyAyEFTUxMA)

Port of my Jelly answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 49 bytes

```
,[[-<+>>++++<]>[[-]<<<[[.>]<---------.[-]]>[-]],]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJzpa10bbzk4bCGxi7YC8WBsbm@hoPbtYG10Y0AOKAuWAhE7s//8ODpoOQKypCQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 15 bytes

```
f/@\)+/ ËÅç"@)
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVA&code=Zi9AXCkrLyDLxeciQCkg&input=IkBAKUBAQCkpKSI)

Comment: [15 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVA&code=Zi9AXCkrLyDLxeciQCkg&input=IkBAKUBAQCkpKSI)

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, I haven't golfed in Japt recently

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
œl”)ḟ”@⁾@ jⱮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5JxHDXM1H@6YD6QcHjXuc1DIerRx3f///zU1HRw0gQBIAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 34 bytes

```perl6
{~map {'@)'xx.chars-1},m:g/\@\)+/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/NjoIwFIXX9iluDBmsOjBsZqExuVs38wLIosF2hqQgoZhAGHx1vFSCxJ/@pf3uOeemuSz0d5fWH2rXNZdU5NC4yN2q8uI/UZjPoF2nm1//gAe@8ttuy9SpAGe5//F0kkkDDZul/sJbcnDhn3Z/9bcEa3CSDHZwcb6Gp6xyGZfyaGEwQBGXZ6EJqQXpOdFETaSZHCXUaWZEDXMlEr0BCg/JEcGoDUdbBIMnHMzRnIJbkNrIe04ujJnknM7lg561HfJ@0M@QTxe78ReVex3fGC1jtsbQHsgRn9Uk7ecTxQljfRv7uAI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 28 bytes

```ruby
$_= ~/@/&&'@) '*$'.count(?))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYoxDoAwDAP3viJDRQgC@gIgP0GCBQbaCsrAwtMJRMWWfE7k/ZwuifvqE1hXgx3beQlbrAGhBxQ7dnA7dkWBTICVxXYOp0/lQCTCpDIZuXCm0TTMxPx/1B/1NDp7Qkxr8Ic08QU)

**Explanation**

```ruby
                                # -p gets a line of STDIN
$_=                             # Set output to
    ~/@/                        # Find first '@' in input
                                # nil (falsey) if not found
        &&                      # If found, set output to
          '@) '                 # Sliced gimbap
               *                # Repeat
                $'              # In the string after the first '@',
                  .count(?))    # ... count the number of ')'
                                # -p outputs the contents of $_
                                # nil outputs as a blank string
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, 49 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("^\\)+|@+","").replace(")","@) ")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bVDLjgIhELz7FZ0@0Zl1PkCzhv2A9eLRR8IiGlzEydBjYtRvH2HEg85AQqgquqjugzqr8WH732qnQoBfZf11BGA9m3qntIF5ggALrq3fgxb5Emga@fsoHoEVWw1z8PANbRjPQlmbysXiH@cEblYrKm6ywC9EeikCKWJJgNROk0nV/Llokr3OJ7uFY8ySv1uuQdEzCJvAIlamhV2Id26AlQPkO@7pH1CSlEMuaX@SskelBNibV9dj9yCP1Pqq4dzl4hLYHMtTw2UVRXZedHKBE8DCl/oJKbve2wc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>91</s> <s>90</s> <s>85</s> <s>71</s> <s>70</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
StringReplace@{(StartOfString~~")"..)|"@"->"",")"->"@) "}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@z@4pCgzLz0otSAnMTnVoVojuCSxqMQ/DSJcV6ekqaSnp1mj5KCka6ekpAPkAmkHTQWl2v8BQBUlDlpuCvoOCtVAMRBQ0lGAsuBsBzgTRELZYMJB08EBIQuCEKYDlAHSC7QHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 30 bytes

```
s/)\?@\()\?\)/\1/g; s/)/@) /gp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfM8beIUYDSMZo6scY6qdbKwDF9B00FfTTC/7/19R0ACIg1vyvmwcA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Unfortunately, your code can't handle leading `)`s and multiple `@` properly. And, how about using [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfM6bGQVPfQVNBP73g/39NTQcgAmLN/7p5AA)?

Comment: As you can see in 5th or last example, leading `)`s have to be ignored.

Comment: @LegenDUST, you are right! it was not that easy. I guess the working version is much uglier

Comment: 28 chars: s/^)*//;s/[^)]//g;s/./@) /gp

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
*?}\@z/>zxz\@\)0"@)
```

[Try it online!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=*%3F%7D%5C%40z%2F%3Ezxz%5C%40%5C%290%22%40%29+&input=%29%40%29%29%40%29%29%29&debug=0) Note that there is a trailing space at the end of the program. This one is (or rather, started out as) a rather direct translation of the Python 2 answer (though the lstrip part was surprisingly difficult).

Explanation:

```
*            # repeat string
  ?          # repeat count: ternary
    }\@z     # condition: check whether input contains @
    /        # if condition is true: count occurrences of one string in another
      >      # array slice: all elements of array (or string) from a specific index and upwards
        z    # the thing to slice (input)
        xz\@ # the index first occurrence of \@ in z
      \)     # string to count occurrences of (\x is shorthand for "x")
    0        # value when ternary condition is false
  "@) "      # the string to be repeated (automatically terminated by end-of-line)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [krrp](https://github.com/jfrech/krrp), 63 bytes

```
^":\L,^*':?#?E'E!-@1#!r'?=#!f'$64.-?*L$64.L$41.L$32.-@0#!r'.0".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy4qKvivaPc/TskqxkcnTkvdyl7Z3lXdVVHXwVBZsUjd3lZZMU1dxcxET9deywdE@6iYGAIJYyM9XQcDkBI9AyW9/zE@CooOIGkFRU2QAi4uOwUfBx9NGHRF46OJOaCKgGk4HyrqAFbngK4WjjXh6hA8qNmu///lF5Rk5ucV/9fVLS4pAgA)

---

## Explanation

```
^":                   ~ take the string as a parameter named `"`
 \L                   ~ import the list module
 ,^*':                ~ apply a binary function
  ?#?E'               ~  if the string is empty,
   E                  ~   return the empty string; else
   !-@1#!r'           ~   define `-` as the cut Gimbap
   ?=#!f'$64.         ~    if an at sign is seen,
    -                 ~    return the cut Gimbap; else
    ?*                ~    if an at sign has been seen,
     L$64.L$41.L$32.- ~     return a Gimbap piece together
                      ~     with freshly cut Gimbap; else
     @0#!r'           ~     proceed to cut
 .0".                 ~ to zero and the above taken string
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLBjtowFLznKyawEmK1QbvtqoddFXJBveQTqlUc8kKsJbZlm7b00E9vaptAgLXqKLH8MuMZP8@71qpPl4iMP6ip4YJQLktYiYpgW8KOdVXNQL@UJmO4FP3b5CVKt@z9SDFWc7EFM2BQTLOOLGkIN9coJ2WC70V0A94pqe1RlRuLTtb7HSV4eLufvXyEM6V2BydRccH0Ac1ebKzzlwCr6Wo9@4AHby7tcQPqlD08OALWMT@AJrvXIrACduC@gnaGPC/N8qdpqmc3vFMns9J3wdM3e4tvvKuY8rTV12nazO6@PC@uaN4hE2AWhm@Fd2iIRDCILGrw0uEoMfrD6j5KuxZqncnKKV3IofDuirvnJ/f5/GmRHXknPTYoQXHauFuXW3IWdALEo@XHT25bNC5Frbu2qFnkj5FmAkrLDbnwuFQ6XoLF42QRC6DEb9LSnawODWGV/EEhlmK4uN4lL81D39O5P9v/o/cK07py6zY0SbJEkRfz07MeZcnYm58BMNby60qYz@uhmgdcfos9v/MzblwNe6/7v1L56Js@y9xB/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 42 bytes

```powershell
''+($args|sls '(?<=@.*)\)'-a|% m*|%{'@)'})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5bDsIgEEX/WcXEUGFq6wKMjSzExDRK1QS1ljaalK4d6UNF0@jAB8w5cyG/3GShD1IpS7OktozNOE2LvTZaaWB8tUzEPMQ1sjg1AZxCE9RMIGvQNoQITsBVxF2rLRaBO4G3GX4aY86IKf6G9fTd6X3P@LoKFGIk1Y9s1w8ufOo/7H0GwUAAdcfo8ZxXZQRU3nO5LeUOEqCbHhVSV6p0jSnNBrEDE8oHFsvraxAXz4kJaewD)

Unrolled:

```powershell
$arrayOfCuttedGimbaps = $args|select-string '(?<=@.*)\)' -AllMatches|% Matches|%{'@)'}
''+($arrayOfCuttedGimbaps)    # toString and output
```